# What is the default HtmlUnitDriver timeout for page loads?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit-driver

What is the default timeout that HtmlUnitDriver uses when waiting for a page to load?

Which functions in the HtmlUnitDriver API can I call to get the timeout value?

```
HtmlUnitDriver h = new HtmlUnitDriver();
```

I don't see any gettimeout function in the JavaDoc of WebDriver or HtmlUnitDriver.

Additionally, if this timeout is too short, how do I set a bigger timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get(url)` is the method used to load web page in browser. But for that I coulnd't find out what is exact timeout for page load looking at [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#get%28java.lang.String%29)

If, in your case, page isn't loaded and timeout error is thrown then you can use [pageLoadTimeout](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#pageLoadTimeout%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) method.

Comment: How do i access this timeouts object from the webdriver? This looks like an inner class/interface. I don't see any function where i can access or set this object?

Comment: You can achieve that using - `driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the timeout default, the htmlunit driver contains the htmlunit object and there is an options object which contains a timeout of 90 seconds, so i assume that this is the timeout

Answer (score 2):

You can use pageLoadTimeout to set the timeout if you want.

Refer : http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#pageLoadTimeout%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29